# Where are bank loans in balance sheet?

Tags: finance, corporate-finance

I am looking at the balance sheet of Coca-Cola (https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/coke/financials/balance-sheet), but I cannot guess where loans with banks are. These liabilities accounts are:

---

ST Debt & Current Portion LT Debt   25.23M  25.94M  6.45M   7.06M   7.53M
Short Term Debt     -   -   -   -   -
Current Portion of Long Term Debt   25.23M  25.94M  6.45M   7.06M   7.53M
Accounts Payable    79.48M  69.45M  109.87M 162M    251.98M 
Income Tax Payable  -   2.52M   -   -   -
Other Current Liabilities   111.6M  110.91M 111.11M 157.49M 198.4M
Dividends Payable   -   -   -   -   -
Accrued Payroll     49.42M  49.4M   51.19M  68.99M  84.74M
Miscellaneous Current Liabilities   62.19M  61.52M  59.91M  88.49M  113.67M

---

But debt is bonds, accounts payable refer to money owed to suppliers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accounts_payable). Is it under "Other Current Liabilities"?. How can I know? Anyone has experience looking at balance sheets? I'm learning this.

Comment: These are current liabilities, you should check the long-term liabilities section. The current portion of long term debt is a bank debt or a bond due to expire within 12 months.

Comment: The link is not working for me, but “debt” refers to both bank loans and issued bonds. You would need to go to the original company report to see how the items are classified; a data provider will convert the company data into a standard template (which in this case, does not distinguish a bank loan from a bond).

Answer (score 2):

In the link one can very clearly see that the company has no contractually short term debt, and in the short-term (i.e. in the next 12 months) has to pay part of its long term debt. Also, that the debt amounts are *not* included in the line "Accounts payable"

[image]

Also, one can see its long term debts

[image]

And no, debt is not only bonds.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Brian for the suggestion, and the others too. It took me a long time to find it in the Coca-Cola report, and it was under Current Liabilities:

> LIABILITIES AND EQUITY
>   CURRENT LIABILITIES
>   Accounts payable and accrued expenses
>   $9,490 $9,660
>   Loans and notes payable
>   12,498 13,129

Page 75 of document: http://www.coca-colacompany.com/content/dam/journey/us/en/private/fileassets/pdf/investors/2016-AR-10-K.pdf

I see, as Alecos suggested, that debt includes both loans and bonds. Itwas my mistake to assume debt is only bonds.